# Jboss (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.remote]

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x

I am experiencing problems with deploying a war project to Jboss 7.1.1. What happens is this:

1. JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
     service jboss.remoting.endpoint.subsystem (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.remote]
2. "Add service" with correct information comes up.
3. [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 4747ms - Started 140 of 156 services (1 services failed or missing dependencies, 15 services are passive or on-demand)

In my standalone XML I have the following concerning naming: 
    subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:1.0"

Her comes the console log:

```
15:06:38,299 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA

15:06:38,451 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA

15:06:38,489 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting

15:06:38,986 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers

15:06:38,997 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 18) JBAS011800: 
Activating Naming Subsystem
15:06:38,999 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 23) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension

15:06:39,002 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem

15:06:39,003 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)

15:06:39,054 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final

15:06:39,146 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service

15:06:40,083 INFO  [com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx] (MSC service thread 1-4) ARJUNA032010: JBossTS Recovery Service (tag: JBOSSTS_4_16_2_Final) - JBoss Inc.

15:06:40,091 INFO  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (MSC service thread 1-4) ARJUNA012324: Start RecoveryActivators

15:06:40,096 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA

15:06:40,112 INFO  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Expired Entry Monitor) ARJUNA012296: ExpiredEntryMonitor running at ti, 24 sep 2013 15:06:40

15:06:40,136 INFO  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (MSC service thread 1-4) ARJUNA012343: RecoveryManagerImple is ready. Socket listener is turned off.

15:06:40,136 INFO  [com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx] (MSC service thread 1-4) ARJUNA032013: Starting transaction recovery manager

15:06:40,167 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol] (MSC service thread 1-7) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on *host*

15:06:40,175 INFO  [com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx] (MSC service thread 1-4) ARJUNA032017: JBossTS Transaction Service (JTA version - tag: JBOSSTS_4_16_2_Final) - JBoss Inc.

15:06:40,218 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Jboss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments

15:06:40,243 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found project.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called project.war.dodeploy

15:06:40,428 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.remoting.endpoint.subsystem (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.remote] 

15:06:40,448 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "project.war"

15:06:41,903 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-5) JNDI bindings for session bean named Project in deployment unit deployment "project.war" are as follows:


15:06:42,138 INFO  [org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.metadata.MetadataBuilder] (MSC service thread 1-6) Add Service
 id=Project
address=http://*host*:8080/project
implementor=com.package.project.Project
 invoker=org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker
 serviceName={http://*host*/}ProjectService
 portName={http://*host*/}ProjectPort
 wsdlLocation=null
 mtomEnabled=false
 properties=[org.jboss.as.webservices.metadata.modelEjbComponentViewName -> service jboss.deployment.unit."project.war".component.OddsCreator.VIEW."com.package.project.Project".SERVICE_ENDPOINT]

15:06:42,343 INFO  [org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean] (MSC service thread 1-6) Creating Service {http://"host"}ProjectService from class com.pacjakge.project.ProjectRemote

15:06:42,712 INFO  [org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-6) Setting the server's publish address to be http://*host*:8080/project

15:06:42,817 INFO  [org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.WSDLFilePublisher] (MSC service thread 1-6) WSDL published to: file:/C:/Jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/data/wsdl/project.war/PorjectService.wsdl

15:06:42,823 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015539: Starting service jboss.ws.port-component-link

15:06:42,843 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015539: Starting service jboss.ws.endpoint."project.war".Project

15:06:42,847 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.DefaultEndpointRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-2) register: jboss.ws:context=project,endpoint=Project

15:06:42,923 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /project

15:06:42,929 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 4827ms - Started 140 of 156 services (1 services failed or missing dependencies, 15 services are passive or on-demand)

15:06:42,953 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "project.war"
```

Here is my standalone.xml as well:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<server name="PC" xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.0">
    <extensions>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.connector" />
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner" />
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.ee" />
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3" />
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx" />
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.logging" />
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.naming" />
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.security" />
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.threads" />
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.transactions" />
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.web" />
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.webservices" />
    </extensions>
    <profile>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
            <console-handler name="CONSOLE" autoflush="true">
                <level name="INFO" />
                <formatter>
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n" />
                </formatter>
            </console-handler>
            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE"
                autoflush="true">
                <level name="INFO" />
                <formatter>
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n" />
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log" />
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd" />
                <append value="true" />
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
            <logger category="com.project">
                <level name="WARN" />
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="CONSOLE" />
                    <handler name="FILE" />
                </handlers>
            </logger>
            <root-logger>
                <level name="INFO" />
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="CONSOLE" />
                    <handler name="FILE" />
                </handlers>
            </root-logger>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.0">
            <deployment-scanner name="default" path="deployments"
                scan-enabled="true" scan-interval="5000" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir"
                deployment-timeout="60" />
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0" />
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:1.1">
            <session-bean>
                <stateless>
                    <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="slsb-strict-max-pool" />
                </stateless>
            </session-bean>
            <pools>
                <bean-instance-pools>
                    <strict-max-pool name="slsb-strict-max-pool"
                        max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5"
                        instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES" />
                    <strict-max-pool name="mdb-strict-max-pool"
                        max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5"
                        instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES" />
                </bean-instance-pools>
            </pools>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jca:1.0">
            <archive-validation enabled="false" />
            <bean-validation enabled="false" />
            <default-workmanager>
                <short-running-threads blocking="true"
                    allow-core-timeout="false">
                    <core-threads count="10" per-cpu="20" />
                    <queue-length count="10" per-cpu="20" />
                    <max-threads count="10" per-cpu="20" />
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="SECONDS" />
                </short-running-threads>
                <long-running-threads blocking="true"
                    allow-core-timeout="false">
                    <core-threads count="10" per-cpu="20" />
                    <queue-length count="10" per-cpu="20" />
                    <max-threads count="10" per-cpu="20" />
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="SECONDS" />
                </long-running-threads>
            </default-workmanager>
        </subsystem>
<!--        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.0"> -->
<!--            <jmx-connector server-binding="jmx-connector-server" -->
<!--                registry-binding="jmx-connector-registry" /> -->
<!--        </subsystem> -->
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:1.0" />
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.0">
            <security-domains>
                <security-domain name="project" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module
                            code="com.project.auth.PackageCheckingLoginModule"
                            flag="required" />
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="UsersRoles" flag="required" />
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
            </security-domains>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:threads:1.0" />
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:1.0">
            <core-environment>
                <process-id>
                    <uuid />
                </process-id>
            </core-environment>
            <recovery-environment socket-binding="txn-recovery-environment"
                status-socket-binding="txn-status-manager" />
            <coordinator-environment default-timeout="300" />
            <object-store />
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.0"
            default-virtual-server="default-host">
            <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" socket-binding="http"
                scheme="http" />
            <virtual-server name="default-host">
                <alias name="localhost" />
            </virtual-server>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.0"
            xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:jaxwsconfig="urn:jboss:jbossws-jaxws-config:4.0">
            <wsdl-host>
                localhost
            </wsdl-host>
            <modify-wsdl-address>true</modify-wsdl-address>
        </subsystem>
    </profile>
    <interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}" />
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}" />
        </interface>
    </interfaces>
    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets"
        default-interface="public">
        <socket-binding name="http" port="8080" />
        <socket-binding name="jmx-connector-registry" port="1090"
            interface="management" />
        <socket-binding name="jmx-connector-server" port="1091"
            interface="management" />
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712" />
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713" />
    </socket-binding-group>
</server>
```

Can anyone guide me in the right direction here, I am pretty much stuck.

Thanks!
OM

Comment: Could you please paste stack trace...

Comment: Sure, I have updated my question now with the console log @ritesh

Comment: Could you please paste your standalone.xml? It seems to me that there might be some subsystem configuration problem...

Comment: @ritesh - No problem, I have edited the question now. I got the same thought, but what is missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To anyone experiencing the same issues. The problem was in the Jboss configuration, standalone.xml. I needed to add the following subsystem to resolve the dependencies:

1. On the top of the xml file, add the following to the extensions section.

`<extension module="org.jboss.as.remoting"/>`

1. Then add the following to the profile section.

`<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:1.1"/>`

Hope half my day will be worth something to someone else :-)

Comment: This error could also be caused if one adds multiple http listeners.